# Find minimum spanning tree of undirected weighed graph with root node having exactly k edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

Having an undirected graph with `v` vertices and `e` edges with each edges having a non-negative weight of at most `w`, the task is to find(if possible!) a subset of edges that connects all vertices with minimum cost. Also this graph has a root node which in the sub-graph should only be directly connected to exactly `k` other vertices(so it most have exactly k edges connected to it in the sub-graph). The algorithm should work in `O(e⋅log(v)⋅log(w))` time.

So after some thinking I thought that we need to find a `minimum spanning tree` since it gives us the `Minimum-cost subgraph` which takes `O(e.log(v))` time.However for insuring that the root node has exactly `k` edges in the resulting tree I couldn't come up with any working idea.

I think that maybe changing the weights of k edges that are connect to the root may enforce their selection,since in the Kruskal's algorithm we first sort the edges, if we pick exactly `k` edges that are already connected to the edge root in the graph and change their weights to some minimum amount then in the tree construction phase, chances are that this k edges make it to the MST. There are still problems here:
**K edges should be picked so that it would be possible for them to make it to an MST**.

Comment: So making the minimum spanning tree and checking if any node has k edges is not OK?

Comment: Every node in a spanning tree is the root of a tree with exactly V-1 edges. So there's something missing in the description of the problem. Perhaps an example would help.

Comment: @Surt I think there might be more efficient ways

Comment: @user3386109 by k edges I meant that the root edge in the original graph should have exactly be connected to k nodes with one edge in the spanning tree

Comment: any constraints?

Comment: @Primusa no, I made it up myself but I want to know the optimal time complexity

Comment: @Primusa   I updated the question to be more clearer and added so of my own thoughts. Hope it would clear things up

Comment: @user3386109 can you explain why do we need such a cut for it to work?

Comment: @user3386109 also what do you mean by smaller and larger maximum `w`? `w` is already the maximum weight. and can this be done in `log(w)` time?

Comment: @user3386109 the two middle nodes can be root for k = 2

Comment: @user3386109 sorry but can't understand it